# How can I create a diagram for the complement of a single set?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drafted a simple code for drawing the complement of a single set, but it seems to shade the entire universal set, including the set of interst itself. Is there a way I can fix this given the code below? I am not too familiar with the Tikz pacakge... thanks so much in advance.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5)}
\draw \firstcircle;
\begin{scope}
 \clip \firstcircle
 \draw[fill=gray] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\node[above] at (0, 1) {\(A\)};
\draw (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2) node [text=black,below left] {$U$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You cannot `clip` a hole into a larger shape. But you can use the even-odd fill style and combine both paths into one. This `even odd rule` means: fill the first (sub-)path, subtract the next from this path and so on.

See the section "15.5.2 Graphic Parameters: Interior Rules" in the [current manual for Ti*k*Z](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for more information on this.

In more or less one line:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=lightgray, even odd rule] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2) 
    node[text=black, below left] {$U$}
    (0,0) circle (1.5) 
    node[midway, below, yshift=1.5cm] {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]